# Failed to create database android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException

Tags: android, sqlite

When I create a `trigger` in `sqlite` this error occurs:

**Error:**

```
Failed to create database
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TRIGGER tr_cell AFTER INSERT ON cell_info
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            UPDATE
                cell_info
            SET first_seen = (select datetime(first_seen,'-4 hour','-30 minute')) where (id=NEW.id AND 10 < (SELECT strftime('%s','now') - (SELECT strftime('%s',first_seen) from cell_info c where c.id = id)))
```

This is my sql **code**:

```
drop trigger if exists tr_cell;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_cell AFTER INSERT ON cell_info
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE
            cell_info
        SET first_seen = (select datetime(first_seen,'-4 hour','-30 minute')) where (id=NEW.id AND 10 < (SELECT strftime('%s','now') - (SELECT strftime('%s',first_seen) from cell_info c where c.id = id)));
    END;
```

The SQL code works successfully in [DB Browser for SQlite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) but when building the app the above error occurs.

Comment: Would you mind sharing where do you put your sql? As a string in your java/kotlin file? Maybe there's an issue regarding the character encoding, that prevent android studio to compile your sql

Comment: `from cell_info c where c.id = id)));  END;` remove c after `cell_info`

Comment: uninstall app then run app

Comment: check in your manifest file and check the flag allowBackup and set it false because sometimes it prevents the DB operation